Trying to use a generic payload to decode the data
I'm trying to decode the data part of a generic response, but for some reason I'm not quite understanding how to specifically use the generic response object to decode the data value. Here is what I have..

let mockData = """
        {
          "status": "ok",
          "data": [
            {
                "name": "Pikachu"
            },
            {
                "name": "Squirtle",
            },
            {
                "name": "Eevee",
            },
          ]
        """.data(using: .utf8)

struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let data: T
}

protocol APIManagerProtocol {
    func loadData<Value: Decodable>(endPoint: EndPoint) async throws -> [Value]
}

actor APIManager: APIManagerProtocol {
    static let shared = APIManager()

    private let session = URLSession.shared
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    func loadData<Value: Decodable>(endPoint: EndPoint) async throws -> [Value] {

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        let payLoad = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response<Value>.self, from: mockData)
        if payLoad.status == "ok" {
            return payLoad.data
        } else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidPayLoad
        }
    }
}

public enum EndPoint: String {
    case characters = ""
}

// Model

struct Pokemon: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var name: String
}

// How it's called

let pokemon: [Pokemon]? = try await api.loadData(endPoint: .characters)

It could probably work without the Response struct, but it would be good to be able to use it in order to capture the status. Thx.

Note, the response you get from your EndPoint.characters url is not
your struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable.
The json response has no status and no data in it.
Add print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)") just after
let (data, response) = try await ... and you will see what you get from the server.
Once you have you model struct properly setup, try decoding with let payLoad = try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data)

Thanks! Yep, you're right, I updated my question so hopefully it makes more sense now. I wonder if there's a way to extract the data using the Response objects data?

Note, your mockData is not valid JSON. Does my answer not work for you, using your original server EndPoint?

Starting with your code base,
try this approach using a Codable ApiResponse struct that matches the json data you get from the server. From that you can extract the array of [ListItem],
then later you could get the pokemons from each ListItem url.
Here is my fully working example code (SwiftUI, use something similar for other systems), to fetch the data from the server and
decode it into some models and display it in a list:
See also this SO post/answer for how to get your pokemons data
SO post
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [ListItem] = []
    let api = APIManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
        .task {
            do {
                let response: ApiResponse = try await api.loadData(endPoint: .characters)
                items = response.results
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ApiResponse: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let next: String
    let previous: String?
    let results: [ListItem]
}

struct ListItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, url
    }
}

protocol APIManagerProtocol {
    func loadData<Value: Decodable>(endPoint: EndPoint) async throws -> Value
}

actor APIManager: APIManagerProtocol {
    static let shared = APIManager()

    private let session = URLSession.shared
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    func loadData<Value: Decodable>(endPoint: EndPoint) async throws -> Value {
        guard let url = URL(string: endPoint.rawValue) else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidURL
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    //    print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)\n")
        let payLoad = try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data)
        return payLoad
    }
}

public enum EndPoint: String {
    case characters = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
}

EDIT-1:
to decode your cleaned up mockData, use this:
let mockData = """
                    {
                      "status": "ok",
                      "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "Pikachu"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Squirtle"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Eevee"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                    """.data(using: .utf8)!


let payLoad = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response<[Pokemon]>.self, from: mockData)

or in your loadData
let payLoad = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response<[Value]>.self, from: mockData)



struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let data: T
}
struct Pokemon: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

